# Scheduling assistant is greyed out

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When trying to schedule a meeting, I tried checking the user availability using scheduling assistant but i can see only my scheduled all the other participants list is greyed out.

Tried following steps and none of them helped in solving the issue:

1. Deleted the participant and added him back.
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled the outlook application.
3. Changed to exchange mode and tried.

And,I dont see this issue when iam using my outlook account on web ,It only happens with desktop application.

> [image]

Comment: Are you sure you are permitted to view the user's calendar? Did you wait long enough? Loading calendars is slow.

Comment: yes.I hope i have required access because available schedule does show up while using outlook via web.And Yes i did wait for a while .

Answer (score 0):

Please contact the user whose status greyed out and confirm if he gives you the correct permission, as mentioned by @YukiSun-MSFT in this thread:

[Scheduling assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588148/scheduling-assistant.html#:%7E:text=Please%20check%20the%20permission%20settings%20of%20your%20calendar%20to%20see%20if%20the%20permission%20to%20view%20full%20details%20has%20been%20accidentally%20granted%20to%20the%20user%3A)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.